# How to display users calendar in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, cocoapods

Does anyone know of the best way to import a users calendar events into a prebuilt calender object. Currently i'm looking at using

https://github.com/jivesoftware/PDTSimpleCalendar

but my problem i'm having is how to use event kit to actually import the users current calendars. I've already got event kit set up where the user can add an event etc to the calendar but am not sure about the best way to display these events. If this is too vague, please let me know, i don't know of any other way to word it.

Thanks!

Comment: I also don't need people to just google 'how to build a calendar' - i'm looking specifically for something which out of the box supports displaying the calendars from the calendars app, preferably as a pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.list of some calendar components that may be helpful for you to create the UI.[click hear](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar)

2.mini-tutorial [click hear](http://www.whatsoniphone.com/blog/ios-advanced-programming-event-kit-framework/)

3.code  sample[click hear](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html)

this may help you